# tslint:disable-next-line won't work for jsx prop error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using react-select, I want to pass a prop that doesn't exist, but the lib is throwing an error, I try to skip it by putting `disable-next-line`, it won't work. But the code is doing fine, I believe it's a false positive, any clue why how to solve this issue?

```
<Select
  /* tslint:disable-next-line */
  handleClick={handleClick}
/>
```

Comment: maybe try disabling the tslint for the <Select /> or for the entire file whatever suits your need.

Comment: @sb39 I don't want to exclude the entire file

Answer (score 2):

This error is related to `typescript` and not `ts-lint`
You can suppress this error by using `@ts-ignore`

```
<Select
  // @ts-ignore
  handleClick={handleClick}
/>
```

Comment: this will ignore the next line or the entire file?

Comment: It will disable next line

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `// tslint:disable-next-line` instead of `/* tslint:disable-next-line */`

refer [TSLint rule flags](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/)

Comment: not working https://imgur.com/a/Krhf6fv

Comment: What is specific error message that you get? Can you please post the error message that you get when you hover over the `handleClick`?

Comment: `Property 'onHandleClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<Props<unknown, boolean, GroupBase<unknown>>, "form" | "name" | "theme" | "className" | "id" | "aria-errormessage" | ... 24 more ... | "`

Comment: it's a false positive.

Comment: The error message that you have posted in not related to tslint. it about the typescript. you will not be able to suppress this error message by disabling the tslint for that specific file/line. 

you will have to define a type or an interface for the onHandleClick.